# How to save image, generated by qrcode, Django?

Tags: django, django-views

How to load image to bd, well i generate qr image(QRcode)when she is generated, i need to create a new record in bd, to save this image and code himslef

This is my model

```
class QRCode(models.Model):
    user                                = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, default=None)
    qr_code                             = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    qr_code_img                         = models.ImageField(upload_to="qr_code_img/", width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    upcoming_show                       = models.ForeignKey(SectionUpcomingShow)
    width_field                         = models.IntegerField(default=270)
    height_field                        = models.IntegerField(default=270)
    is_active                           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp                           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated                             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - - {1}".format(self.user.username, self.is_active) 

    class Meta:
        ordering                        = ["-timestamp"]
        verbose_name                    = 'QRCode'
        verbose_name_plural             = 'QRCodes'

    @property
    def image_path(self):
        return os.path.abspath(self.qr_code_img)
```

this is view to gen qrimg

```
def qr_code_generator(hex_code, username, __show__id, __show__name__, __show__q, price):
    qr_code_generate_himslef = pyqrcode.create(hex_code)
    generate_name       = ''.join(username + '_' + str(__show__id) + '_' + __show__name__ + '_' + str(__show__q) + '_' + str(price) + '.png').replace(" ", "_")
    qr_code_generate_himslef.png(generate_name, scale=6)
    print(qr_code_generate_himslef)
    return qr_code_generate_himslef
```

when i print this function i got this

`QRCode(content=b'f40a03cb6026d68f0f83c43b47c9e388ed106848', error='H', version=5, mode='binary')`

this is my save view

```
new_qr_code, created = QRCode.objects.get_or_create(user=get_user_profile, qr_code=hex_code, is_active=True, defaults={"user":get_user_profile, "qr_code":hex_code, "qr_code_img":qr_img, "upcoming_show":get_upcoming_show})
if not created:
    pass
```

Comment: when you run the function qr_code_generator() the qr image is created in your root directory. you can then read that image and send it as a parameter to your get_or_create function. thats it.

Comment: @AnkushVerma i understand that, but how to send it as parametr?

Comment: @AnkushVerma pls tell me how to read img and upload like, i upload from admin panel, specific in folder media_cdn

Comment: @AnkushVerma Simply, I managed to load the picture, but the full path is shown, that is, straight where everything lies, the path specified by default is not shown, for example /media_cdn/qr_img_code/asdasd.png
Here so is not present, there C: and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run this function

```
def qr_code_generator(hex_code, username, __show__id, __show__name__, __show__q, price):
    qr_code_generate_himslef = pyqrcode.create(hex_code)
    generate_name       = ''.join(username + '_' + str(__show__id) + '_' + __show__name__ + '_' + str(__show__q) + '_' + str(price) + '.png').replace(" ", "_")
    qr_code_generate_himslef.png(generate_name, scale=6)
    print(qr_code_generate_himslef)
    return qr_code_generate_himslef
```

the qr_code image file will be produced in your root directory(the directory having your manage.py file) with the name 'generate_name' variables value.

then open that image like

```
import os
from django.core.files import File

with open(generate_name, 'rb') as qr_img:
   new_qr_code, created = QRCode.objects.get_or_create(user=get_user_profile, qr_code=hex_code, is_active=True, defaults={"user":get_user_profile, "qr_code":hex_code, "qr_code_img":File(qr_img), "upcoming_show":get_upcoming_show})
   if not created:
      pass
```

and your qr_image will be uploaded to your 'upload_to' location given in models field. you can put this code in try block to avoid exceptions.

you can then remove the useless qr code image generated by that function

```
os.remove(generate_name)
```

hope it helps...